# Working with Protected Sheets and Ranges "View Only" mode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just want to ask if there is a way for a user to use a button with a **lock** or **unlock** script even if the permission on **Protected Sheets and Ranges** is in "**View Only**" mode? Will using a web app work or it is still impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

A script cannot protect/unprotect a sheet or range if the user executing it doesn't have `edit access` to the protected sheet/range.

Trying to do so this result in a message like:

> You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

In order to avoid the script throwing this exception, it's useful to first check if the user has edit access, using [Protection.canEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#canedit).

#### Using a web app:

When you [deploy a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app), you can set **Execute the app as: Me** (that is, the user deploying the web app). If this user has edit access to the protected sheet/range, the web app will be able to unprotect the sheet/range, even if it's accessed by a user who doesn't have edit access.

For example, let's say you have a spreadsheet with a sheet named `Sheet1`, which is protected and can only be edited by user #1. In this case, you could have the following `doGet` function to unprotect it:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Sheet unprotected!");
}
```

And then, while logged in with user #1, deploy the web app the following way:

- Click `Publish > Deploy as web app...`.
- Set `Execute the app as: Me`.
- Set `Who has access to the app:` to an audience that will include the other users who should be able to access this.
- Click `Deploy`.
- Copy `Current web app URL:`.

Finally,  access this URL with user #2 (which doesn't have edit access to the protected sheet). The sheet will become unprotected.

#### Update:

You could write another function to access this URL programmatically via [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). See, for example:

```
function unprotect() {
  const url = "WEB_APP_URL";
  const options = {
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  }
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Accessing this URL via `UrlFetch` might require [setting scopes explicitly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in the [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) of the script:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]
```

Comment: Will this work with this error: `Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.`?

Comment: @cjvdg This will work successfully if you follow the guide I provided. Specially take into account: (1) deploy the web app **while logged in with a user who can edit the protected range/sheet**, (2) set `Execute the app as: Me`, (3) unprotect the sheet/range by accessing the web app URL, not by executing `doGet` directly. Of course, you could create another function in your script to access this URL programmatically, using UrlFetch. I edited my answer in order to show you how this could be done. See section `Update` in my answer.

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm currently getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProtections' of null at doGet(Code:12:28)`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @cjvdg That means you don't have a sheet called `Sheet1`, so `getSheetByName` returns `null`. You should change `Sheett1` in the code snippet to your sheet name. And in general, you adapt this code snippet to your situation (I'm not sure whether you have a protected sheet, or ranges, or what have you).

Comment: Alright. I'll double check it. Thank you!